# PyCharm: как указать путь к static папке, где лежат js/css/images файлы веб проекта?

Tags: pycharm, webstorm

В корне проекта есть две папки:

- `templates` -- тут лежат jinja2 шаблоны
- `static` -- тут лежат папки с javascript-ами, картинками и стилями.

Как сделать так, чтобы когда я редактировал бы файл шаблона из `templates`, PyCharm понимал бы пути. Например:

```
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

этот путь PyCharm у меня понять не может, он понимает лишь если шаблоны и статик файлы в одной папке.

Я пробовал эти папки помечать как <kbd>template folders</kbd>, но ничего не помогло.

В WebStorm то что я ищу называется как Resource Root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фича `Resource Root` появилась в PyCharm 4.5 версии.